# How to change font family of ListView items

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a ListView and I'm using the standard "native" template and groups.

How do I set the font for the text in the group header and the item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the text and detail labels using this...

```
public class MyTextCellRenderer : TextCellRenderer
{
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);

        if (cell.TextLabel.Font.FamilyName != CommonStyles.RegularFontName)
        {
            cell.TextLabel.Font = UIFont.FromName(
                CommonStyles.RegularFontName, cell.TextLabel.Font.PointSize);

            cell.DetailTextLabel.Font = UIFont.FromName(
                CommonStyles.RegularFontName, cell.DetailTextLabel.Font.PointSize);
        }

        return cell;
    }
}
```

For the section headers, this works initially...

```
UILabel.AppearanceWhenContainedIn(typeof(UITableView)).Font = ...
```

When the section header has been scrolled off screen and back on again, it reverts to the standard though.

But this works...

```
public class CustomTableViewRenderer : TableViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TableView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            Control.Source = new CustomTableViewModelRenderer(e.NewElement);
        }
    }
}

public class CustomTableViewModelRenderer : UnEvenTableViewModelRenderer
{
    public CustomTableViewModelRenderer(TableView model) : base(model)
    {
    }

    public override void WillDisplayHeaderView(UITableView tableView, UIView headerView, nint section)
    {
        if (headerView is UITableViewHeaderFooterView view)
        {
            view.TextLabel.Font = UIFont.FromName(CommonStyles.RegularFontName, 18);
        }
    }
}
```

That's a lot of code to change some fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for setting dynamic `LayoutOptions` in `ListHeader`, like wise you can pre-set these attributes for individual label and customize your header. now as what you want, you can set your own font family or colour or font size, or may be customize your header cell, It is just an `ItemTemplate`

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView" IsGroupingEnabled="true">
    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label
                    HorizontalOptions="{Binding Optn}"
                    Text="{Binding Heading}"
                    VerticalOptions="{Binding Optn}" />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: There’s no mention of font family in your example. I was hoping to avoid using a custom template.

Comment: in the heading label you can use prop. `FontFamily` and it is `ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate` Property when you want to use font family, you need to specify it somewhere. Two reference links:1)https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts . 2) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.groupheadertemplate?view=xamarin-forms